# Controller Action that takes values from 2 dropdownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an action Home controller that takes parameters from 2 DropDownLists.
My goal is to persist the selected value from each dropDownList so as whenever the action is called, both parameters are defined.
My problem is that every time I select a new value to either of DropDownLists, the value of the other one is reseted.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Results ( int? PageSize,int? RaceId, int page = 0)
        {                      
            ///code that uses PageSize and RaceId to get data from DB             
        }

public ActionResult _SelectRaces(int id=3)
        {          
            var results = db.Races.Where(r => r.Event_Id == id);
            if (results == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var r in results.ToList())
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = r.Name, Value = r.id.ToString() });
            }

            ViewData["Race"] = items;
            return PartialView(results.ToList());
        }

public ActionResult _SelectPageSize()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });

            ViewData["PageSize"] = items;
            return PartialView(items);
        }
```

**Views:**

_SelectRaces.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        Select Race
        @Html.DropDownList("RaceId", ViewData["Race"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width: 150px;", onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
    </fieldset>
}
```

_SelectPAgeSize.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        Select Page Size
        @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", ViewData["PageSize"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width: 50px;", onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
    </fieldset>
    ViewBag.PAge = "Page";
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @Html.Action("_SelectPageSize")<!--Select Page Size-->
    @Html.Action("_SelectRaces") <!--Select Race-->
    @Html.Action("Results")
```

Comment: A little unclear what your trying to achieve. You have not shown the POST methods. I assume you wanting to redirect back to `Results` and pass both `PageSize` and `RaceId` to it? If you want to persist the values, then use a view model with properties for those values, return the view model to the `Index.cshtml` method and pass it to the `_SelectPageSize` and `_SelectRaces` methods when you call `Html.Action()`. And then generate a hidden input for the other property.

Answer (score 0):

in that case I used a viewmodel and partial views:

Example:

IndexViewModel.cs

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> Races { get; set; }
    public int raceSelected { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> PageSize { get; set; }
    public int pageSizeSelected { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var results = db.Races.Where(r => r.Event_Id == id);
        if (results == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var r in results.ToList())
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = r.Name, Value = r.id.ToString() });
        }
        var pageSizes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        pageSizes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
        pageSizes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
        pageSizes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });

        var model = new IndexViewModel()
        {
            Races = items,
            PageSize = pageSizes
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

in your Index:

```
   @this.model IndexViewModel
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SelectPageSize", this.Model); }<!--Select Page Size-->
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("_SelectRaces", this.Model); }    <!--Select Race-->
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("Results", this.Model); }
```

_SelectRaces.cshtml(example) and _SelectPAgeSize:

```
@this.model IndexViewModel

    <fieldset>
            Select Race
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.raceSelected, this.model.Races, new { style = "width: 150px;", onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
        </fieldset>
```

in submit method

```
    public ActionResult Results (IndexViewModel model)
            {   
var raceId = model.raceSelected;
var pageSize = model.pageSizeSelected; 

                ///code that uses PageSize and RaceId to get data from DB             
            }
```